# Cannot install any softwares from software center in Ubuntu 14.04. Install icon is greyed

Tags: software-center

[image: Example snapshot]

This is just example. It is same for software download pages including VLC, Synaptic Package Manager etc.
Please any one help me. I reinstalled ubuntu & also updated just now and the problem is still the same.

Comment: how you are connected to internet?

Comment: I connect to internet through Airtel 3g Dongle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using some software to connect to internet sometime **network manager** will not recognise your connection. Then you wont be able to install softwares through software center.

I had a similar problem and it solves when I disables network manager by running this command in terminal.

```
       sudo stop network-manager
```

Then software center greyed out **install** option will become normal.

Comment: It didn't work for me.  Rather my internet stopped working after running this command and I had to run `sudo start network-manager` to up the internet.